# Including compiled PDFs in documentation built by l3build

Tags: compiling, dtx, docstrip, l3build

I am building a project with *l3build*. There are some examples I want to present in the documentation, showing their source code, annotated with *DocStrip*, as well as including the output they produce using `\includegraphics` to pull in the PDF generated from the extracted example source code. It all looks roughly like this:

- `examples.dtx`:

  ```
  %    \begin{macrocode}
  \documentclass[a8paper]{scrartcl}
  \begin{document}
  %<*italic>
  %    \end{macrocode}
  % Here is some italic text.
  %    \begin{macrocode}
  \textit{Lorem ipsum}
  %    \end{macrocode}
  %    \begin{macrocode}
  %</italic>
  %<*bold>
  %    \end{macrocode}
  % And here is some bold text.
  %    \begin{macrocode}
  \textbf{Lorem ipsum}
  %</bold>
  %    \end{macrocode}
  % That is all.
  %    \begin{macrocode}
  \end{document}
  %    \end{macrocode}
  ```
- `examples.ins`:

  ```
  \input docstrip.tex
  \generate{\file{italic.tex}{\from{examples.dtx}{italic}}}
  \generate{\file{bold.tex}{\from{examples.dtx}{bold}}}
  \endbatchfile
  ```
- `documentation.drv`:

  ```
  \documentclass{ltxdoc}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \begin{document}
  Let me present some examples.
  \DocInput{examples.dtx}
  This is how the examples look when compiled. \\
  \includegraphics{italic.pdf} \\
  \includegraphics{bold.pdf}
  \end{document}
  ```
- `build.lua`:

  ```lua
  #!/usr/bin/env texlua
  -- build.lua - not working
  module = "example"
  typesetfiles = {"documentation.drv"}
  kpse.set_program_name("kpsewhich")
  dofile(kpse.lookup("l3build.lua"))
  ```
- shell commands to do what `build.lua` is intended to do (`typeset.sh`):

  ```bash
  tex *.ins
  for doc in *.tex
  do
    pdflatex "$doc"
  done
  pdflatex *.drv
  ```

[I placed these files on GitHub for you to quickly download and test them.](https://github.com/dffischer/l3build-complex-doc)

I even thought of rather drastic measures like redefining the `typeset` function in terms of `arara`. But I cannot seem to configure l3build to compile the documentation correctly. The examples do not need to be distributed in any TDS or  `*.zip`, but they have to be unpacked and compiled before typesetting the documentation. Can this be done with l3build?